# pigpiod callback is exiting my code

Tags: python-3, pigpio, pi-gpio

I have the following code:

```
def read_adc(adc, lsb):
# first read 
adc.writebytes([0x8E]) # ask for channel 0
my_bytes = adc.readbytes(2)  # read channel 
value = (my_bytes[0] << 3)
print(value*lsb*4.01)
# second read
adc.writebytes([0x8E]) # ask for channel 0
my_bytes = adc.readbytes(2)  # read channel 
value = (my_bytes[0] << 3)
print(value*lsb*4.01)

    # sending pulses with PWM
def tx_pulses(pi, GPIO, frequency, num, dutycycle=0.5):
    assert 1 <= frequency <= 500000
    assert 1 <= num <= 65535
    assert 0.0 <= dutycycle <= 1.0
    duration = int(1000000/frequency)
    on_micros = int(duration * dutycycle)
    num_low = num % 256
    num_high = num // 256
    wf = []
    #                           on      off    time
    wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO,       0, on_micros))
    wf.append(pigpio.pulse(      0, 1<<GPIO, duration - on_micros))
    pi.wave_add_generic(wf)
    wid = pi.wave_create()
    if wid >= 0:
        pi.wave_chain([255, 0, wid, 255, 1, num_low, num_high])
        while pi.wave_tx_busy():
            time.sleep(0.01)
        pi.wave_delete(wid)

...
#=======================================================
## FOR THE PWM
#=======================================================
pi = pigpio.pi()
GPIO_PWM=19
pi.set_mode(GPIO_PWM, pigpio.OUTPUT)


#=======================================================
## Read from ADC while PWM'ing
#=======================================================
lsb = 0.004  # 4.096/1024 
#process for PWM
pwm_p=Process(target=tx_pulses, args=(pi, GPIO_PWM, 1000, 65535))
pwm_p.start()
while(pwm_p.is_alive()):
    cb = pi.callback(19,pigpio.RISING_EDGE, read_adc(adc, lsb))
```

The goal is to read my ADC on a rising edge. However, my code exits after a few callbacks, and the pwm_p process is still alive. I know this because I have connected a scope to the GPIO output, and we still see the waveform. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the code is written in your question, it is creating an unlimited number of callbacks.  Eventually the system will fall over because of a lack of resources.

Also a pigpio callback receives a set number of parameters (being gpio, level, and tick).  You can't pass the return value of a function call as a callback.

Change

```
while(pwm_p.is_alive()):
    cb = pi.callback(19,pigpio.RISING_EDGE, read_adc(adc, lsb))
```

to

```
def mycallback(gpio, level, tick):
   read_adc(adc, lsb)

cb = pi.callback(19,pigpio.RISING_EDGE, mycallback)
while(pwm_p.is_alive()):
   time.sleep(1)
```